# How can I remove and reinstall MySql (reinstall does not bring back deleted "root" user.)

Tags: mysql

Before I uninstall mysql... 
lets remove the user "root"

```
mysql -u root -e "delete from mysql.user where user not in (x);"
mysql -u root -e "flush privileges;"
```

the above statement says remove all users from mysql except for user "x"

let's remove mysql completely from centos.

```
service mysqld stop
yum remove mysql -y
yum remove mysql-server -y
```

and then let's re-install it.

```
yum install mysql -y
yum install mysql-server -y
service mysqld start
```

now let's try to login as "root".

```
mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

error says root can not login.

my goal is to "COMPLETELY" remove mysql and then re-install it as if this was the first time install.

how can this be achieved ?

Comment: You may need to run `rm -Rf /var/lib/mysql` just before reinstalling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your databases are probably still there, try to remove the data directory.

```
rm -r /var/lib/mysql
rm /etc/my.cnf
```

Comment: This was my initial thought, but I added it as a comment instead. +1 to you :)

Answer (score 0):

### Overview

You've used 2 specific commands;

- yum remove
- yum install

#### What does `yum remove` do

> Are  used  to  remove  the specified packages from the system as well as removing any packages which depend on the package  being removed. **[Source](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/yum8.html)**

- You have `-y` to default `Y` to all questions

#### What does `yum install` do

> Is  used  to install the latest version of a package or group of
>   packages while ensuring that all dependencies are satisfied.  If no  package  matches the given package name(s), they are assumed to be a shell glob and any matches are then installed. **[Source](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/yum8.html)**

So, we can say you've;

- Removed the specific package `mysql` from the system

  - and packages that depend on `mysql`
- Installed `mysql`

From the `man` page, you can see it ***only*** removes the package (and packages depending on that package), but does not explicitly say it removes the data.

### To fix your issue

You need to remove the data held in your `mysql/` directory to **completely** remove it.

```
rm -Rf /var/lib/mysql
```

Or (create a backup)

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_backup
```

Answer (score 0):

I am writing for similar problem happened to me on windows 10 with MySQL, i.e., server not starting after re-install.

1. Uninstall the MySQL (all components) from control panel.
2. Delete MySQL from C drive (C:\Program Files and C:\Program Files (x86))
3. Delete from C:\ProgramData\MySQL and App Data.
4. Also clear using %temp% and temp
5. Try install.

Worked for me. All the best!!